# How do I get Start-Job to accept script parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters, background-task, start-job

I have a PowerShell script that does multiple things, and takes in a delay parameter (time in seconds). I want to kick off a background job that plays a sound after a time defined by the delay parameter.

So the user enters something like:

```
.\RunMyScript -delay 10
```

In my script, my param block looks like this:

```
param([int]$delay, [switch] $cleanup)
```

Now, the $delay parameter works everywhere in my script, but it doesn't work when I use Start-Job. I tried both the following approaches, and neither worked.

APPROACH 1

```
$PlayStartSound = {
        Start-Sleep -s $delay
        [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play();
    }
Start-Job $PlayStartSound
```

APPROACH 2

```
Start-Job –Scriptblock {Start-Sleep -s $delay; [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play();}
```

Both approaches play the sound immediately, ignoring the delay. If I replace $delay with a number say like so, then it works:

```
Start-Job –Scriptblock {Start-Sleep -s 10; [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play();}
```

I'm curious as to why $delay is not in scope, and how I can fix this? Thanks for looking.

Comment: `$delay` -> `$using:delay`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the answer is to use the -ArgumentList parameter to supply the $delay parameter. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
Start-Job –Scriptblock {Start-Sleep -s $args[0]; [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play();} -ArgumentList $delay
```